# Why use _ prefix in JS when encapsulation can be achieved with scoped variables?

Tags: naming-conventions, encapsulation

I've just started a new job with rigorous in-house code standards. One of them, that I've seen plenty of times before in Javascript, is using `_` as a prefix for the properties of an object that should not be accessed from outside that object.

My de facto personal coding standard tends to use a lot of functions and primitives, and when I exposes an object with methods these will usually be syntactic sugar, aliases for generic plugins to be repeatedly used: I tend to keep everything very tightly-scoped such that each function has a distinct purpose and is only given the data it needs. As a result, within any given scope, only the bare minimum is exposed, and everything is private by default.

The underscore-prefixed-properties convention is closely related (as I see it) to two other big conventions here, one being Hungarian notation, the other being the use of a monolithic god object that *everything* must be added to. So I can see how, culturally, the `_` fits in well since

1. Everything must be exposed as a property (of a property, etc) within a global object
2. Seeing as any piece of code can thus see any other piece of code, a meta-coded system is used to try and help programmers not trample each-other's code by mistake

The coding standards are held on a pedestal, but they were received, such that nobody here can adequately explain what they're for, or why. My cynical perspective is that in the earliest instance, developers either didn't see fit to implement generic, decoupled code, or didn't know how to encapsulate in JS, and later on the Hungarian notation was developed to allow some consistency while effectively having to compensate with human cognitive effort for the inherently dangerous code architecture.

Can anybody give me a less cynical explanation of the value of exposed but `_`-prefixed properties?

Answer (score 0):

A reason to use _ prefixes (also sometimes m_) is to make a distinction between instance variables on the one side and local variables and parameters on the other side, so they cannot be mixed up, especially if they have the same name.
Another reason would be to make a distinction between non-public instance variables and publicly visible properties, which are backed-up by the instance variables and should thus have the same name. In languages like VB.NET this distinction cannot be made via casing, so a prefix is added.